# What does it mean, "swept the numbers for months now"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Matthew speaks to Michael, weed dealer:

> Matthew: Run the numbers by me again.
>
> Michael: 200 million gross p.a., 100 million net. But your people know
>   this already. They've **swept the numbers for months now**. The bottom
>   line is I'll sell it to you for 400 million.

What does it mean, "swept the numbers for months now"?

I find these line in *The Gentlemen 2019*

Comment: Probably 'follow closely the figures relating to some company being discussed', e.g. earnings, profit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "sweep" can mean "to search methodically" (dictionary)

Presumably "your people" (ie the accountants who work for you) have been searching "the numbers" (ie the statistics about the company's performance) for information about its future potential.

Answer (score 0):

It says they've been following the numbers for months now. They already know them, and there is no reason to go into detail.

From [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sweep),

> - (transitive) to search (a place) methodically

From [collinsdictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sweep),

> - If someone makes a sweep of a place, they search it, usually because they are looking for people who are hiding or for an illegal activity.
>
> > Two of the soldiers swiftly began making a sweep of the premises.
> >
> > There may be periodic police 'sweeps' of crime in the area.
>
> - to search (a room, area, etc) electronically to detect spying devices
> - to pass swiftly over or across; traverse, as in search
>
> > searchlights sweeping the sky